# Why my Module is not being loaded in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that runs perfectly on my OSX environment. Now Im creating a Ubuntu env from scratch and having a weird class loading issue on my Rails application.

Inside my app/models/MDMS.rb I have

```
class MDMS
  include HTTParty

  base_uri APP_CONFIG.mdms_url

  def self.ip2location(ip)
    Rails.cache.fetch("MDMS#ip2location(#{ip || 'empty'})", expires_in: 15.days) do
      request("/api/v1/ip2location", { ip: ip })[:data]
    end
  end
```

And in my application_controller I have a call for this model. Like this:

```
 if @zip.blank?
    byebug
    #guess from IP
    #r = MDMS.ip2location(request.remote_ip)
    r = MDMS.ip2location("216.189.182.112")
    @zip = session[:zip]  = r['zip_code']
    update_user_zip_attributes(r)
    if !@zip.blank?
      set_legacy_zip_cookie(r['zip_code'])
    end
  end
```

The problem is. When I try to run it I got an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ip2location' for MDMS:Module):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:90:in `current_zip'
```

So, I dont know why this is happening. Maybe a classloader issue? Someone have ideas on what to try to solve this?

Thank You

Comment: name your file in lower-case, `mdms.rb`. And do you also have a module `MDMS`?

Comment: I changed it to mdms in lowercase and it works.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you can answer the question if you want. The first is the right one. Thank you!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I can confirm the same as you and thus will remove my comment. It appears this is only an issue when there is a mix case situation like `RESTful #=> "res_tful"`

Answer (score 2):

> Inside my app/models/MDMS.rb I have

Your files should be named in snake_case. In this particular case, it should be named `mdms.rb`